# Image slider using Datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, slider, datalist

I'm looking for something similar to the image slider on ebay.

[image]

Using datalist to retrieve the images.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
<ItemTemplate>                      
    <asp:ImageButton height="270px" width="200px" ID="Prod_ImageLabel" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Prod_Image") %>' />                                                 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Look for a javascript library using google, and then use the library that you like and render what its need there using asp.net.

Comment: Hi Mish, thank you for posting a question on stack overflow. To get answers quicker, it helps to explain what you have tried, what didn't work and what seemed to be "on the right track". Posting code snippets, third libraries you've tried, etc might help contributors.